# c++ mapping of topic name to vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, vector

[So I was given this question and 20 minute to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s2Kk.png)

Here is the start of the function body

```
typedef map<string, vector<string>> TopicMap; 
typedef map<string, int> TopicCount; 

vector<string> split (const string& line, char delim =' ')
{
    vector<string> strs; 
    size_t pos = line.find(delim); 
    size_t initialPos = 0; 
    while (pos != string::npos) 
    {
        strs.push_back(line.substr(initialPos, pos-initialPos));
        initialPos = pos+1; 
        pos = line.find(delim, initialPos);
    }
    strs.push_back(line.substr(initialPos, pos - initialPos)); 
    return strs; 
}

TopicCount countTopicOccurences (const TopicMap& topicMap, const vector<string>& reviews)
{
   //TODO complete me 
   for (string reviewword:reviews) {
   }

}
```

Basically I have inputs vector as a list of reviews and a map of topics (string) to key words making up the topic (vector).  I have to output the number of times a topic name maps to each review.

I just have no idea how to solve this question it 20 minutes since understanding this question takes about 5 minutes. The c++ split string function is given.

I tried to break this question up by using a for_each loop for each review, and then using a for_each loop for_each loop for individual topics. So if a topic maps to a single review, I will increment the mapping of that topic by 1. But I find this really hard to write down workable code.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Linking to an image like that is frowned upon. Out of curiosity, was this 20 minutes on your own, or 20 minutes with an interviewer? Sometimes getting to the end isn't necessary, but what you do with those 20 minutes that's important. How you think, what questions you might ask, etc.

Comment: How would you recon I ask the question then? Perhaps taking the time to type out the code in a code block? And this was an online question, not in person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to split the reviews into words with the provided function.  Then you need to search these words in the topic map.

A very primitive answer just iterates thorugh the topic map again and again.  It's not optimized but definitively something doable in 20 minutes:

```
TopicCount countTopicOccurences (const TopicMap& topicMap, const vector<string>& reviews)
{
    TopicCount c; 
    for (string reviewword:reviews) {
        auto words=split(reviewword);
        for (auto& word:words) {
            for (auto m:topicMap) {
                if (find(m.second.begin(), m.second.end(), word) != m.second.end() )
                   c[m.first]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return c; 
}
```

Of course, the dataset provided doesn't give the expected answer.  But this is not related to this counting function, but on the bad split() function provided, which uses only one delimiter.  So punctuation is handled as if it was a letter of a word, which causes some matching words not to be recognized. I let you as an exercise this improvement, as well as the optimization.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/JlfxlH).